# Rails cannot generate model using mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, mysql2

Windows XP with installed MYSQL as a development machine, ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32], Rails 3.1.0
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL S
erver 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\inc
lude"'  (successfully installed gem mysql2)
rails new talk -d mysql  (successfully created a new rails app called talk)

---

PROBLEM NOW STARTS:

---

C:\Sites\RP\talk>rails generate User
ERROR MESSAGE:
ruby.exe-Unable to Locate Component
This application has failed to start because libmysql.dll was not found.  Re-installing the application may fix this problem.
COMMAND LINE ERROR MESSAGE:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2.rb
:9:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/RailsInsta
ller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (Load
Error)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/
lib/mysql2.rb:9:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18
/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/RP/talk/config/application.rb:9:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in`'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in`'

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150580 has the answer. for some reason I need to:

1/ gem install mysql 2/ copy the libmysql.dll file from /MYSQL/MySQL Server 5.5/lib and paste it to Ruby1.9.2/bin

after that, it is smooth sailing...

Even though I did it, I would appreciate if anyone has an insight into the reason behind the solution.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150580  has the answer.  for some reason I need to:

1/ gem install mysql
2/ copy the libmysql.dll file from /MYSQL/MySQL Server 5.5/lib and paste it to Ruby1.9.2/bin

after that, it is smooth sailing...

Even though I did it, I would appreciate if anyone has an insight into the reason behind this:

Answer (score 0):

On windows there should be a LIB environment variable.  Have you checked to make sure that the path to libmysql has been added to this?  I suspect it hasn't.