# Rails cannot generate model with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux

I'm a ruby on rails noob and am having an issue generating a model using mysql.  I got a new project going without errors:

```
rails new my_project -d=mysql
```

but then when I attempted to create a new model for posts, nothing happened.  The command-line just sort of froze for about 10 minutes until I went into htop and killed the process.  The syntax I was using was as follows:

```
rails g model post title:string content:text
```

What might be going on here?  I found a similar complaint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8205817/2540204) from 2011 but it, along with the ruby forum link seemed like an entirely different error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give us error log?. I would recommend  to cross check database.yml. Login to mysql from command line and check if db created.  Try running rake db:create and rake db:migrate

Comment: @Hemali thanks for the response!  `rake db:create` creates a database successfully.  `rake db:migrate` seems to run successfully (at least it doesn't complain)  When you ask for the error log, are you asking for the contents of `log/development.log`?  If so, there are none.  Thanks again!

Comment: error log when you run rails g model Post title:string context:text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stopping Spring with `spring stop` and then run the generator again.

[When trying to generate a model with Rails and PostgreSQL, the command hangs without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749247/when-trying-to-generate-a-model-with-rails-and-postgresql-the-command-hangs-wit)

Answer (score 0):

Model names on this command should always be capitalized

```
rails g model Post
```

That's the only fault I can see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey, good syntax catch; thanks.  Unfortunately it didn't seem to impress my command-line. :-P

Comment: Oh, too bad. Could be a MySQL configuration issue then. Have you concluded that the database itself works/worked on earlier projects? Correct gems, permissions, etc.

Comment: That's sort of what I'm thinking. Rails seemed to work just fine with sqlite and mysql seems to work well with anything other than rails.

Comment: as far as I remember the rails generator understands both formats, `rails g model my_post` and `rails g model MyPost` will both work